# Threejs - Import collada model looks funny on Chrome Android, textures are not properly loaded

Tags: android, webgl, collada

I tried to import a .dae model using the provided `ColladaLoader`, it worked great on desktop but on Chrome on Android I'm issuing some problems. The Geometry is loaded, but the textures are not properly loaded. It seems that textures are applied to the object but they are not rendered with the proper colors , it looks all light blue.
Any one has an idea what I'm doing wrong? Is something related with anisotropic filtering (since I noticed that is not supported on chrome mobile ?)[image]

Comment: How big are your textures? Android has a lot less memory than your Desktop

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the three.js creator himself is that this is a bug in the Qualcomm GPU driver related to the fog glsl code.  To avoid this bug, turn off all phong mateirals' fog attribute.

```
phongMaterial.fog = false;
```

No fog on android until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the working and non-working examples on threejs.org site, I found the culprit for the bluish texture.  It is the shadow mapping of directional light.  Somehow this code below is causing problem on android devices.

```
            light.castShadow = true;
            light.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
            light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;

            var d = 390;

            light.shadowCameraLeft = -d * 2;
            light.shadowCameraRight = d * 2;
            light.shadowCameraTop = d * 1.5;
            light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

            light.shadowCameraFar = 3500;
```